# I am getting an NZEC error in codechef

Tags: java

Getting an NZEC error while submitting this code in codechef.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Codechef 
{

    public static void main(String[] args)throws java.lang.Exception 
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int test=sc.nextInt();
        for(int i=1; i<=test; i++)
        {
            int n=sc.nextInt();
            Integer num=n;
            int length=(int)Math.pow(10, num.toString().length()-1);
            while(length>0)
            {
                System.out.println(num);
                num%=length;
                length/=10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you understand what NZEC error means?  Non Zero Exit Code.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an input file where the number of integers to follow is greater than the actual number of integers, nextInt throws a NoSuchElementException.

Use `hasNextInt` to test the availability of another number in the input.

```
for(int i=1; i<=test; i++){
    if( sc.hasNextInt() ){
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        // etc.
    }
}
```